# Chrome's Regexes - Can I view them?

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome

Html5 input types includes many new types.

(range , Email , date etc...)

For example :

`<input type="url"   >`

[image]

I know that IE used to have regex store ( on one of its internal folders)

**Question :**

Can I see in what regexes does chrome use to validate the input ?

Is it under a viewable file or something ?  / how can I see those regexs ?

Comment: How do you even know it's a regex?

Comment: @Kobi i'd bet my life on it

Comment: @RoyiNamir: It **may** use regexes (a series of them), but as it's a browser, it probably has a more robust way to validate URLs. I'd [look through the source](http://dev.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/get-the-code), it'll be Chromium or WebKit, both are open source.

Comment: It might be written as regex but the rules for well formed email or url are so laxist that those regexes are probably deceptively simple. And I fear you'd lose your life on this.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - or [Blink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blink_%28layout_engine%29).

Comment: @Kobi: True, although they probably haven't had time to change this bit of WebKit in Blink yet. :-)

Comment: You can check webkit's source [here](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/html?rev=154721&order=name)

Comment: @RoyiNamir Did you lose your life already ? ;)

Comment: @dystroy Half life :-) ( cuz the Email does use regex while URL doesn't...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I looked up the source code of Blink. Keep in mind I never saw it before today, so I *might* be completely off. 
Assuming I found the right place -

For `type="url"` fields there is [`URLInputType`](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/blink/+/9d8fc44892f633b1448d0daa638969ffac497bc4/Source/core/html/forms/URLInputType.cpp), with the code:

```
bool URLInputType::typeMismatchFor(const String& value) const
{
    return !value.isEmpty() && !KURL(KURL(), value).isValid();
}
```

`typeMismatchFor` is called from [`HTMLInputElement::isValidValue`](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/blink/+/master/Source/core/html/HTMLInputElement.cpp)

```
bool HTMLInputElement::isValidValue(const String& value) const
{
    if (!m_inputType->canSetStringValue()) {
        ASSERT_NOT_REACHED();
        return false;
    }
    return !m_inputType->typeMismatchFor(value) // <-- here
        && !m_inputType->stepMismatch(value)
        && !m_inputType->rangeUnderflow(value)
        && !m_inputType->rangeOverflow(value)
        && !tooLong(value, IgnoreDirtyFlag)
        && !m_inputType->patternMismatch(value)
        && !m_inputType->valueMissing(value);
}
```

[`KURL`](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/blink.git/+/master/Source/platform/weborigin/KURL.h) seems like a proper implementation of a URL, used everywhere in Blink.

In comparison, the implementation for [`EmailInputType`](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/blink/+/9d8fc44892f633b1448d0daa638969ffac497bc4/Source/core/html/forms/EmailInputType.cpp), `typeMismatchFor` calls `isValidEmailAddress`, which does use a regex:

```
static const char emailPattern[] =
    "[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~.-]+" // local part
    "@"
    "[a-z0-9-]+(\\.[a-z0-9-]+)*"; // domain part

static bool isValidEmailAddress(const String& address)
{
    int addressLength = address.length();
    if (!addressLength)
        return false;

    DEFINE_STATIC_LOCAL(const RegularExpression, regExp,
                        (emailPattern, TextCaseInsensitive));

    int matchLength;
    int matchOffset = regExp.match(address, 0, &matchLength);

    return !matchOffset && matchLength == addressLength;
}
```

These elements and more can be found on the [/html](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/blink/+/9d8fc44892f633b1448d0daa638969ffac497bc4/Source/core/html/) folder. It seems most of them are using proper parsing and checking of the input, not regular expressions.

Comment: I checked in Chrome: `http://שלום.com` is a valid URL, but `שלום@example.com` is an invalid email - the regex above does not support Unicode.

Comment: I wonder why they are treated differently. (Email by regex VS Url which is not)...

Comment: @Kobi good job. I've a question : How do you search the online repository you link to ? You don't ?

Comment: @dystroy - Thanks! I googled for something like "blink source code" and found [the root](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/blink/). I tried searching just in `site:chromium.googlesource.com/chromium` but found mostly diff logs which I can't read (they're confusing for me), and aren't interesting. I went back to the root folder and from there it was mostly programmers' intuition. The source is neat and well organized (at least the parts I needed), and was easy to navigate.